# Dynamic FirstOrDefault Predicate expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, predicate

I basically want to generalize [EF Core Delete Handling in collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#handling-deletes). I have written the below method, but I am not able to construct predicate based on passed key name dynamically. In the case of Many-to-Many relations, the key is composite key e.g. (UserId, RoleId), so there is no dedicated Primary key that I could use from the base class. The method is:

```
public static void InsertUpdateOrDeleteCollection<T>(this ICollection<T> dbVersion, ICollection<T> localVersion, string keyName) where T : IObjectWithState
{
    // If I have passed keyName = DeptId, this can give me L.H.S i.e p => p.DeptId
    Expression<Func<T, object>> pkFieldExpression = ExpressionHelper.ConstructLambda<T>(keyName);

    // I dont't know how to get R.H.S i.e objForeach.Dept 
    // and combine both ofcourse to be served in FirstOfDefault(...)

    foreach (var localVersionItem in localVersion)
    {
        var dbVersionItem = dbVersion.FirstOrDefault(f => f.keyName == localVersionItem.keyName); // <= This is my problem!
        if (dbVersionItem == null)
            dbVersion.Add(localVersionItem);
        else
            dbVersionItem.UpdateItem(localVersionItem);
    }

    foreach (var dbVersionItem in dbVersion)
    {
        if (!localVersion.Any(a.keyName == dbVersionItem.keyName)) // <= And this too!
            dbVersionItem.TrackingState = TrackingStates.Deleted;
    }
}
```

So, basically I want to construct the Predicate dynamically based on foreach iteration object key and the key of the object on which FirstOrDefault has to be made. And the key name is passed as a string param.

```
dbVersion.FirstOrDefault(predicate == value of iteration object);
```

**UPDATE:** Found the solution and added the answer below.

Comment: I guess you gonna need to build your type dynamically and use both (TypeBuilder and GetILGenerator()).

Comment: @Bruno can you please refer some example(s) to me? I've no idea what you are talking about!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it to be working. I am already using an [ExpressionHelper](https://www.codementor.io/@juliandambrosio/how-to-use-expression-trees-to-build-dynamic-queries-c-xyk1l2l82) class by [Julián Andrés D'Ambrosio](https://www.codementor.io/@juliandambrosio). By using a few of the methods from this class, I added a new method:

```
public static Func<T, bool> GenerateComparePredicate<T>(T entity, string propertyName)
{
    var keyProperty = entity.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(prop => (string)prop.Name == propertyName);
    var keyPropertyValue = keyProperty.GetValue(entity);
    var compareExpression = GetCriteriaWhere<T>(propertyName, OperationExpression.Equals, keyPropertyValue);

    return compareExpression.Compile();
}
```

And then updated my method as:

```
public static void InsertUpdateOrDeleteCollection<T>(this ICollection<T> dbVersion, ICollection<T> localVersion, string keyName) where T : IObjectWithState
{
    foreach (var localVersionItem in localVersion)
    {
        Func<T, bool> predicateCompare = ExpressionHelper.GenerateComparePredicate(localVersionItem, keyName);

        var dbVersionItem = dbVersion.FirstOrDefault(predicateCompare);
        if (dbVersionItem == null)
            dbVersion.Add(localVersionItem);
        else
            dbVersionItem.UpdateItem(localVersionItem);
    }

    foreach (var dbVersionItem in dbVersion)
    {
        Func<T, bool> predicateCompare = ExpressionHelper.GenerateComparePredicate(dbVersionItem, keyName);

        if (!localVersion.Any(predicateCompare))
            dbVersionItem.TrackingState = TrackingStates.Deleted;
    }
}
```

Working like charm now!